# How to install Toad-for-mysql on ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I am familiar with toad-for-mysql for mysql database.I want to install toad-for-mysql in ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Is there any way to install ?

Comment: You will need wine for that

Comment: Do you installed it before ?@George

Comment: No I haven't used it before!